# Serilog Memory Sink

Tags: serilog

Is there a Serilog sink that just writes to a buffer in memory?  What I am thinking about is a sink that will store X lines and then I could access those X lines and show them on a web page via an api controller.  This would be more for viewing recent errors that occurred in the application.

I looked on the GitHub sink page (https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks) but did not see one and just wondered if there was something I was missing.

Answer (score 4):

Serilog doesn't have a built-in Sink that writes to memory, but you could easily write one just for that. Take a look, for example, at the **[`DelegatingSink`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/master/test/Serilog.Tests/Support/DelegatingSink.cs)** that is used in Serilog's unit tests, which is 80% of what you would need... You'd just have to store the events in an in-memory data structure.

Another option would be to use the **[`mssqlserver`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#serilogsinksmssqlserver--)** sink, write the events to a simple table, and display in your web app.

A third option (which would be my recommendation) would be to just install **[Seq](https://getseq.net/)**, which is free for development and single-user deployment, and just write the logs to Seq through [their sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-seq). That will save you from having to write the web app, and will give you search and filtering out-of-the-box.

[image: Seq]